# Hibernate criteria LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

For a project I want to get a LEFT JOIN working with criteria but I don"t get what I want.

I want to do this: Select Books FROM UserBooks LEFT JOIN Books ,....
But I don't get anything.

This is what I got at the moment:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Books> getBooksByTitle(int userID, String Title) {
    List<Books> books = null;

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(UserBooks.class, "userBooks");
    c.setFetchMode("userBooks.book", FetchMode.JOIN);
    c.createAlias("userBooks.book", "books");
    c.setProjection(Projections.property( "books") ) ;
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("userBooks.id", userID));
    c.add(Restrictions.like("books.title", "%"+ Title + "%"));

    books = c.list();

    for (Books allBooks : (List<Books>)books) {
              System.out.println(">>>>>" + allBooks.getTitle()); 
    }

    tx.rollback();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
    return books;
}
```

Comment: What table to you want to join with?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I got it :)

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(UserBooks.class, "userBooks");
    c.createAlias("userBooks.book", "book");
    c.setProjection(Projections.property("book"));
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("userBooks.user.id", userID));
    c.add(Restrictions.like("book.title", "%" + Title + "%"));
```